# After deployment at customer end and browse the URL, Website is not launched correctly and throws errors as "Content security policy"

Tags: asp.net, iis, content-security-policy

My asp.net project is working fine at our QA machine and deployed at customer end. But when the browse URL, website is not properly displaying. Some alignment issue at customer side any browser. When I clicked F12,It shows error as "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-yP/phO6MWRqPDsL5fwP/+7pIbMUdA+zgVlj8/r2BJDo='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

It seems server side "Content Security Policy" is missing??

Can any one guide me in above issue what need to be done at server side to fix the above issue as it is working fine in our environments like DEV, QA environments.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer [this blog](https://beaglesecurity.com/blog/article/hardening-server-security-by-implementing-security-headers.html) to add Security Headers in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Content Security Policy set on the customer system. This could be a default policy added or an intentional restriction by the customer. You will first need to find where the policy is added and then either remove or modify it or alternatively change your code.

Based on the error messages you'll need to rewrite inline script and inline style into separate files or add "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'. Note that allowing 'unsafe-inline' is not desired, so your preferred option should be change your code. Noting that violations arise from jquery.min.js it might help to upgrade jquery if the version used is old.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Where can I find the Content Security Policy set on customer system.

Comment: You can use fiddler or postman to capture request and response body so that you can know how client set content security policy.

Comment: Open developer tools in your browser (F12), load the page click at the request in the Network tab and look at response headers. If CSP is set as a meta tag you can view source and search for it, but it is unlikely in this scenorio.